# Using scons with Keil compiler/linker

Tags: scons, keil

I'm trying to use the Keil C51 compiler with scons as a build system.

The final problem I have is how to get `$SOURCES` to be output comma-separated to the linker. The default uses space as separator.

The relevant parts of the SConstruct is

```
path = ['C:\Keil\C51\BIN']
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : path})

#Compiler settings
env['CC']        = 'c51.exe' 
env['CCCOM']     = '$CC $SOURCES $_CPPINCFLAGS $CFLAGS  $_CCCOMCOM ' #-o $TARGET 
env['INCPREFIX']  = 'INCDIR('
env['INCSUFFIX']  = ')'

# Linker settings
env.Replace(LINK='BL51.exe')
env['LINKCOM']     = '$LINK $SOURCES TO $TARGET $LINKFLAGS $__RPATH $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS'
```

With this I get:

> BL51.exe driver.obj flash.obj initialization.obj power.obj TO Outfile.omf

What I want is:

> BL51.exe driver.obj,flash.obj,initialization.obj,power.obj TO Outfile.omf

[$SOURCES](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/a4774.html#cv-SOURCES) is a construction variable and I cant find how to change how it is printed to the command-line.

Anyone?

Comment: I dont think there is a standard way to do that in SCons without creating your own builder.

Comment: Where is it concatenated? Is it implicit from being a list or is it done in scons?

Comment: The Python list separator (look up the string.join(listVar) function) is quite easy to change. Considering that most C/C++ compilers expect a space between files, its probably concatenated internally by SCons. Unfortunately, you may have to write your own builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using:

```
    env['LINKCOM']     = '$LINK ",".join( $SOURCES ) TO $TARGET $LINKFLAGS $__RPATH $_LIBDIRFLAGS $_LIBFLAGS'
```